# Poetry packaging files in .gitigore

Tags: python-poetry

It seems like when using poetry to create pip packages, any .py files that are excluded from git (via .gitignore) are not packaged.

I've got a use case where some .py files are automatically generated from other files that are checked in to git. The autogeneration process happens before poetry creates the package.

Is there a way to indicate to poetry that it should in fact package a given .py file even though it's not source controlled?

Comment: Sounds like a job for the [include](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#include-and-exclude) table. N.B.: _"Explicitly declaring entries in include will negate VCS' ignore settings."_

Comment: Brian61354270's answer above is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can override exclusion of files that are excluded by VCS rules by adding them to the [`tool.poetry.include`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#include-and-exclude) table in `pyproject.toml`. Per the docs,

> ### include and exclude
>
> A list of patterns that will be included in the final package.
>
> [...]
>
> If a VCS is being used for a package, the exclude field will be seeded with the VCS’ ignore settings (`.gitignore` for git for example).
>
> **Explicitly declaring entries in `include` will negate VCS' ignore settings.**

Emphasis mine.